# How to add page restrictions for blocks in drupal?

Tags: blocks

I'm using the drupal administrator menu for the settings
there i have a page called /desert/234234
the block should appear only when the url is /desert/(desert_id)
how can i restrict that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Drupal 7 you can use PHP code in the block's "Visibility settings."

#### Steps

- Go to admin/modules and enable the PHP filter module

  [image]
- Go to admin/structure/block and click on "Configure"

  [image]

  - Enter the following PHP code (including `<?php` and `?>`) in the *Page* settings.

  [image]

Answer (score 1):

on visibility settings, choose two mode of visibility, for example:

- type of content, choose one content type you want your block to show on
- on page visibility, you choose hide for listed page, the type /desert/*/*

Comment: This is valid for Drupal 8, 9 & 10. Be sure to add the URL to "Pages" not "Route".

Answer (score 0):

Make a block appear only when URL is something: On the configuration page of the block go to 
Visibility settings -> Pages -> Show block on specific pages, and select "Only the listed pages." Wildcards may be used if needed; for example, desert/* would match any path starting with desert/.

Comment: i can do if it is a static page like desert/xxxxx        but my url is desert/id. here id is an dynamic content

Answer (score 0):

Drupal 7:
1. Go to: /admin/structure/block
2. Click configure
3. In Visibility settings set "Only the listed pages" and in textarea below insert " /desert/* .

Also remember to activate block - put it in one of regions of the page.

Comment: i can do if it is a static page like desert/xxxxx        but my url is desert/id. here id is an dynamic content

Comment: Wildcard (*) replaces all characters. So url like /desert/* is equal to /desert/123456, /desert/abcdef, /desert/cake/apple and so on.

Comment: let me explain in clear. i'm having two pages desert/(13221)dynamic value and desert/continent.       The block should not display in desert/continent page. how can i restrict?

Comment: Then in the same tab you should switch to "Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)" and write some PHP [Read this for more help on this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7195769/drupal-php-block-visibility-rules). Or you can write your custom module and use [hook_block_info_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info_alter/7).