# How to display a block on only the listed pages using wildcard and excluding subpages?

Tags: blocks, uri

I have a block I'm displaying using block setting's "Only the listed pages". I'm using a wild card asterisk to show the block on any pages following `about-us/`. For example: `about-us/*`

The problem is I ONLY want pages immediately after `about-us/` to show.
For example `about-us/faq` would show the block but `about-us/faq/content` should NOT show the block.

I tried `about-us/*/` but that had no effect.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Method 1. PHP filter**

I think your question is partially answered here:

[How to add page restrictions for blocks in drupal?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/82450/28700)

Only you might use this code:

```
<?php
$arg = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());
if ($arg[0] == 'about-us' && $arg[1] && $arg[2] == NULL) {
  return TRUE;
}
else {
  return FALSE;
}
?>
```

**Method 2: Context module**

Alternatively, you can try the [Context](https://drupal.org/project/context) module, which offers more robust visibility options. For instance, in addition to including paths you can prefix a path with a tilde "~" to *exclude* it.

I think this should do it:

```
about-us/*
~about-us/*/*
```

*Edit: Added second method.*

*Edit: Using $_GET['q'] in method 1 instead of arg() (Thx, @leymannx!)*

Comment: Still getting  false/no-display from this code

Comment: What is the path where you are getting a FALSE return?

Comment: I've added a second method.

Comment: Thanks for the second method. I'd like to avoid installing a module if I can.

Comment: path that was giving me false was: 
/about-us/page

Comment: Hm. That's a basic (and widely used) check. There might be something else going on. Have you tried printing out each the args?

Comment: I know its returning false because if I switch the "TRUE" and "FALSE" in the argument the block displays.

Comment: Switching them is essentially like removing the condition altogether so it doesn't tell us much. I'm happy to help further if you can provide more information about your set-up in the OP (and knowing what arg() is returning would also be a big help). Cheers -

Comment: While using the PHP filter will work, it may be considered bad practice http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/2509/what-are-the-downsides-of-using-custom-php-code-in-blocks-nodes-views-args

Comment: You have to check the path alias, which arg() doesn't.

Comment: @leymanxx is right and I am sheepish. Method 1 corrected to use $_GET['q'] instead.

Comment: You don't need to pass $_GET['q'] to drupal_get_path_alias() as "If no path is provided, the function will return the alias of the current page."

Comment: @superdrupal - Yeah, I know. I have no idea why I did that. I've edited my answer. Thanks much.

Answer (score 3):

Drupal 8 - Simple module to achieve this: 
https://www.drupal.org/project/block_exclude_pages

Simply add the path you want to exclude with a '!' Prefixed.

Example:

!/path/this

Answer (score 1):

Set your block display settings to show on about-us/* then add the following hook to your module.

```
<?php
/**
 * Implements hook_block_list_alter().
 */
function my_module_block_list_alter(&$blocks) {
  $alias = explode('/', drupal_get_path_alias());
  if ($alias[0] == 'about-us' && isset($alias[1]) && isset($alias[2])) {
    // unset the bid (block id)
    unset($blocks[55]);
  }
}
?>
```

*Edit: fixed condition - arg() doesn't return alias.*

Comment: Add to which module?

Comment: Your custom module, please see https://www.drupal.org/node/1074360

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, too.:-P  arg() won't evaluate aliases.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, you can use the [Block Visibility Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/block_visibility_groups) module to very easily combine multiple conditions for one or many blocks. For this case, you can add a page `[path]/*` condition and a negative `[path]/*/*` condition.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP filter module
In Block settings > Pages: check

> Pages on which this PHP code returns TRUE (experts only)

Paste this:

```
<?php
return preg_match('/^about-us(\/[a-z]*)?(\/)?$/',
drupal_get_path_alias($_GET['q']));
?>
```

Comment: Oh, no, It's too late))

Comment: `preg_match()` seemed like a good way to go but unfortunately with this code I was getting int(0) result on both about-us/test-1 and about-us/test-1/test-2.

Comment: Its because after first slash regexp searchs for letters only, did not u see expression?

Comment: Well, now I do. Numbers do show up in aliases time and again so best to cover all bases, no?

Comment: I just gave variant. And it's simple to find how to search for any symbol

Answer (score 0):

There is another alternative to answer this question ... ***which doesn't require the PHP filter to be enabled*** (which you should try to avoid whenever possible) ... Just use the [Rules block visibility](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_block_visibility) module. Here is a quote from its project page:

> The Rules block visibility module allows [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) components to be used to control block visibility. This provides Drupal administrators and developers extreme flexibility in controlling when blocks should be displayed on their websites, in addition to the default visibility options provided by Drupal.
>
> The general idea is that if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility, so the possibilities are limitless.
>
> Need to show a block only for users registered more than a month ago?
>
> Perhaps you have a block that must be shown only between 8am-5pm on weekdays?
>
> What about displaying or hiding a block based on current weather conditions?
>
> All of this can be done by using Rules block visibility.

With that, and as per the "*if you can do it with Rules, you can use it to control block visibility*" above, you've reduced your question to making [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) "***check the path of the current page***" (so that the block is only shown on your pages with a path that **starts with** "`about-us/`", but not on those pages that have a path like "`about-us/*/*`").

For an illustration of how to use this module, refer to my answer to "[How to stop a Views block from displaying to admins, such as user/1?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/109984/how-to-stop-a-views-block-from-displaying-to-admins-such-as-user-1/193173#193173)". It includes a Rules Component (in Rules export format), which you should replace by this variation of it to make it match your specific question):

```
{ "rules_block_visibility_show_on_selected_profile_pages" : {
    "LABEL" : "Show block on selected profile pages",
    "PLUGIN" : "rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules" ],
    "USES VARIABLES" : {
      "module" : { "label" : "Module", "type" : "text" },
      "delta" : { "label" : "Delta", "type" : "text" },
      "result" : { "label" : "Result", "type" : "boolean", "parameter" : false }
    },
    "IF" : [
      { "AND" : [
          { "text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "about-us\/",
              "operation" : "starts"
            }
          },
          { "NOT text_matches" : {
              "text" : [ "site:current-page:path" ],
              "match" : "about-us(\/[a-z]*)?(\/)?$/",
              "operation" : "regex"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [ { "data_set" : { "data" : [ "result" ], "value" : "1" } } ],
    "PROVIDES VARIABLES" : [ "result" ]
  }
}
```

**Note**: the 2nd Rules Condition in the above Rules Component (with the regular expression in it) may need further refinements to perfectly fit your case. I.e. the "`about-us(\/[a-z]*)?(\/)?$/`" part of it (though I think it's pretty close to what your question is about).

Answer (score 0):

The go to Drupal 8/9/10 solution for both including and excluding pages at the same time is the [Condition Path](https://www.drupal.org/project/condition_path) module.

It uses the condition plugin API which makes it useful for all content implementing conditions (such as blocks).

**Example:** To show a block on all product pages but not on the subpage 'reviews', add the following pages in the condition:

- /products/*
- !/products/*/reviews